# Execute data flow task based on multiple input data flow from Expression Task

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl, ssis-2016

Is it possible to execute the data flow task based on multiple Expression task. The expression task contains the source query variable var_srcquery and a dynamic query assigned here  at runtime. There is 4 Expression Task all assigning to the same variable var_srcquery  based on the condition in the precedence constraint. At a time only one Expression task will execute and go to the data flow task as shown in the picture.

When i execute the package it correctly building the dynamic query and getting assigned to the variable var_srcquery  but it is not going to the Data flow task.

[image]

Is the Data flow task accepts only 1 input flow.

Is there any other way to handle this, please let me know.

Comment: Solved...Put all the expression task in the sequence container and then connected to the data flow task...It's worked.

Comment: If only one expression runs per package run. How about one expression with a nested if then else?